# Difference between "what we call" and "what we called"

Tags: passive-voice, past-simple, noun-phrases

> 1. That's **what we called** the star jump.
> 2. That's **what we call** the star jump.

How could I understand these two sentences and tell the difference between them? To my understanding, the second one is general speaking, so it can be rewritten as 'That's what we call the star jump in general.', but what does the first one mean?
Is it:

> 1. (passive structure) That's what is called the star jump.
> 2. (general speaking in past tense) That's what we used to call the star jump.

Comment: 2. is your answer--that's what we called, in the past, the star jump, but we don't anymore. (Either because it got renamed, there's no "we" to speak of anymore, etc.)